# Why is the static keyword preventing a segmentation fault here?

Tags: c, pointers, static, coredump

I was playing around with pointers in C and came across a behavior I don't understand. It involves the use of the `static` keyword in the following program:

```
/**
*      Simple LIFO stack implemented using linked lists
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct LinkedList LinkedList;
struct LinkedList{
        int value;
        LinkedList *next;
};

int pop(LinkedList **list){
        LinkedList *next;
        int ret;        
        ret = (*list)->value;
        next = (*list)->next;
        //free(*list);
        *list = next;
        return ret;
}
void push(LinkedList **list, int value){        
        LinkedList *new = (LinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
        new->value = value;
        new->next = (*list);
        *list = new;
}

int main() {        
        LinkedList *myList;

        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
                push(&myList, i);


        while(myList!=NULL)
                printf("popped %i\n", pop(&myList));          

        return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run the code above, I get a segmentation fault. However, when I change the declaration of `myList` to `static LinkedList *myList`, the program works (seemingly) perfectly:

```
output without static keyword:
popped 9
popped 8
popped 7
popped 6
popped 5
popped 4
popped 3
popped 2
popped 1
popped 0
popped 1
popped 1970220846
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

output with static keyword:
popped 9
popped 8
popped 7
popped 6
popped 5
popped 4
popped 3
popped 2
popped 1
popped 0
```

I don't really understand why that is. I believe that it has something to do with the scope, because the following code works just the same without the need for the `static` keyword:

```
/**
*      Simple LIFO stack implemented using linked lists
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct LinkedList LinkedList;
struct LinkedList{
        int value;
        LinkedList *next;
};

int pop(LinkedList **list){
        LinkedList *next;
        int ret;        
        ret = (*list)->value;
        next = (*list)->next;
        //free(*list);
        *list = next;
        return ret;
}
void push(LinkedList **list, int value){        
        LinkedList *new = (LinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
        new->value = value;
        new->next = (*list);
        *list = new;
}

int main() {        
        LinkedList *myList;

        push(&myList, 0);
        push(&myList, 1);
        push(&myList, 2);
        push(&myList, 3);
        push(&myList, 4);
        push(&myList, 5);
        push(&myList, 6);
        push(&myList, 7);
        push(&myList, 8);
        push(&myList, 9);


        while(myList!=NULL)
                printf("popped %i\n", pop(&myList));          

        return 0;
}
```

I know that the reason for the segmentation fault is that the pop() function is trying to dereference a bad address (since apparently the `myList!=NULL` check isn't working), but for some reason the `static` keyword magically fixes everything!

Only other thing that comes to mind is that it has something to do with passing the reference to the `myList` pointer in the for loop to `push()`. Although I don't know what's wrong with that...

Thanks!

Comment: 'new' is a keyword in C++.  when using a compiler that can compile C++ programs, this will be a problem.  suggest changing 'new' to something more meaningful

Comment: when calling malloc() (and related family of functions) in C, 1) do not cast the return value.  It is already a void * so can be assigned to any other pointer.  2) Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: in the pop() function, once the head pointer is stepped past the first struct instance, the pointer to the struct is only known within that function.  Therefore, the call to free() for the 'disconnected' struct instance must be performed within that function.  The posted code has the necessary statement commented.   Without the call to free(), a memory leak will occur

Comment: in the function: main() the pointer 'myList' needs to be initialized to NULL.  Since the myList->next is not set to NULL on the first call to push(), but to what ever trash is in myList when myList was first put on the stack.  So looping through the linked list does not see a terminating NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uninitialised (and zero initialised) static variables are put into the BSS. The BSS is zeroed by the loader. Hence by making your variable static you are effectively initialising it to `NULL`. Without the static the same variable is allocated on the stack. Uninitialised stack variables can contain any random values (depending on what previously used the stack) and accessing such a variable results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Objects with static storage duration are correctly zero-initialized by the language. "BSS" and "loader" are just details of some particular platform. C language knows nothing about any "BSS" or "loaders".

Answer (score 1):

You did not explicitly initialize your `myList` variable.

When declared as a local (automatic) variable it contains garbage value initially, which is what leads to the crash when you attempt to pop everything from your stack.

When you declare it as `static`, it is implicitly initialized with null pointer value for you, which eventually makes your pop cycle to terminate as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are automatically initialized to `0` by default, so the initial value of `mylist` will be a null pointer when you use the `static` keyword. Then when you loop through the elements of the list, `while (mylist != NULL)` will stop when you get to this null pointer.

Automatic variables are not automatically initialized, so the initial value of `mylist` is garbage. The `while` loop doesn't detect this as the end of the list, and when you try to indirect through this, undefined behavior occurs.

To get the same behavior with an automatic variable, simply specify the initial value:

```
LinkedList *myList = NULL;
```